# Spring boot WebSocketStompClient not receiving messages

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-websocket

Currently, I can see that in the test case I am able to successfully connect and send messages to WS server/endpoint. However, I am not receiving any message. The `completeableFuture` object in the test case waits for the message for 10 secs and then times out. I tried to debug as well into the source code wherein I could see that `session`, `destination`, `subscribers` are loaded correctly

My WebSocketConfig:

```
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
class WebSocketConfig : WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    override fun registerStompEndpoints(registry: StompEndpointRegistry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS()
    }

    override fun configureMessageBroker(registry: MessageBrokerRegistry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker( "/topic/")
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/api/")
        //registry.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user")
    }
```

Controller:

```
class ChatController(private val chatService: ChatService) {

    @MessageMapping("/user/chat/{channelId}")
    @SendTo("/topic/chat/{channelId}")
    fun chatMessage(@DestinationVariable("channelId") channelId: UUID, chatMessageDTO: ChatMessageDTO): ChatNotification {
        return chatService.submitMessage(chatMessageDTO, channelId)
    }
```

Service:

```
 fun establishChatSession(chatChannelDTO: ChatChannelDTO): ChatChannelDTO {
        if (chatChannelDTO.userOne == chatChannelDTO.userTwo) {
            throw InvalidInputDataException("")
        }
        val optionalChatChannel = getExistingChannel(chatChannelDTO)
        return if (optionalChatChannel.isPresent) {
            ChatChannelDTO.fromChatChannel(optionalChatChannel.get())
        } else {
            newChatSession(chatChannelDTO)
        }
    }
```

Test :

```
class ChatControllerIT(@Autowired private val chatService: ChatService, @Autowired private val  simpleMessagingTemplate: SimpMessagingTemplate) {

    @Value("\${local.server.port}")
    var port = 0;

    var completableFuture: CompletableFuture<ChatNotification> = CompletableFuture()
    lateinit var webSocketStompClient: WebSocketStompClient

    @BeforeEach
    fun setup() {
        this.webSocketStompClient = WebSocketStompClient(SockJsClient(listOf(WebSocketTransport(StandardWebSocketClient()))))
        webSocketStompClient.messageConverter = MappingJackson2MessageConverter()
    }

    @Test
    fun verifyGreetingIsReceived() {
        val channel = chatService.establishChatSession(ChatChannelDTO(userOne = UUID.randomUUID(), userTwo = UUID.randomUUID()))
        val stompSession = webSocketStompClient.connect("ws://localhost:$port/ws", object : StompSessionHandlerAdapter() {}).get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        println("subscribing to::::::::::   /topic/chat/${channel.channelId}")

        val message = ChatMessageDTO(message = "Hello", senderId = channel.userOne, senderName = "Pranav", recipientName = "Monika", recipientId = channel.userTwo)
        stompSession.send("/api/user/chat/${channel.channelId}", message)

        stompSession.subscribe("/topic/chat/${channel.channelId}", object: StompFrameHandler{

            override fun getPayloadType(headers: StompHeaders): Type {
                return ChatNotification::class.java
            }

            override fun handleFrame(headers: StompHeaders, @Nullable payload: Any?) {
                completableFuture.complete(payload as ChatNotification)
            }
        })

        val response = completableFuture.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        println(response)
    }
}
```

Any idea on whats going wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

This code looks correct to me. I created example project and it works. Are you sure local.server.port has the correct value. Try this test class. If it doesn't work, contact me directly and I'll send you example project

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class ChatControllerIT(@Autowired private val chatService: ChatService) {

    @LocalServerPort
    var port = 0

    var completableFuture: CompletableFuture<ChatNotification> = CompletableFuture()
    lateinit var webSocketStompClient: WebSocketStompClient

    @BeforeEach
    fun setup() {
        this.webSocketStompClient = WebSocketStompClient(SockJsClient(listOf(WebSocketTransport(StandardWebSocketClient()))))
        webSocketStompClient.messageConverter = MappingJackson2MessageConverter()
    }

    @Test
    fun verifyGreetingIsReceived() {
        val channel = chatService.establishChatSession(ChatChannelDTO(userOne = UUID.randomUUID(), userTwo = UUID.randomUUID()))
        val stompSession = webSocketStompClient.connect("ws://localhost:$port/ws", object : StompSessionHandlerAdapter() {}).get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        println("subscribing to::::::::::   /topic/chat/${channel.channelId}")

        val message = ChatMessageDTO(message = "Hello", senderId = channel.userOne, senderName = "Pranav", recipientName = "Monika", recipientId = channel.userTwo)
        stompSession.send("/api/user/chat/${channel.channelId}", message)

        stompSession.subscribe("/topic/chat/${channel.channelId}", object: StompFrameHandler {

            override fun getPayloadType(headers: StompHeaders): Type {
                return ChatNotification::class.java
            }

            override fun handleFrame(headers: StompHeaders, @Nullable payload: Any?) {
                completableFuture.complete(payload as ChatNotification)
            }
        })

        val response = completableFuture.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        println(response)
    }
}
```

Comment: I copied your class above and its still not working me

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share a GitHub URL of your sample project?

Comment: Sure https://github.com/tulupov/websocket_test   Probably you forget to add @Configuration annotation on your WebSocketConfig

Comment: I found the issue -  I switched to GsonMessageConverter() instead of MappingJackson2MessageConverter() and it worked like a charm :). Thanks a lot for your help